# Expected Declaration error in "for i in 0..<imagesNames.count{ line

Tags: swift3

[image: Screenshot]

Hello everyone, I get an "Expected Declaration" error (quite common), but I have no clue on how to fix it. I dabble in swift a little, but this perplexes me. Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var Loading: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    var imagesNames = ["tmp-0.gif", "tmp-1.gif", "tmp-2.gif", "tmp-3.gif", "tmp-4.gif", "tmp-5.gif", "tmp-6.gif", "tmp-7.gif", "tmp-8.gif", "tmp-9.gif", "tmp-10.gif", "tmp-11.gif", "tmp-12.gif", "tmp-13.gif", "tmp-14.gif", "tmp-15.gif", "tmp-16.gif", "tmp-17.gif", "tmp-18.gif", "tmp-19.gif", "tmp-20.gif", "tmp-21.gif", "tmp-22.gif", "tmp-23.gif", "tmp-24.gif", "tmp-25.gif", "tmp-26.gif", "tmp-27.gif"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

for i in 0..<imagesNames.count{

        images.append(UIImage(named: imagesNames[i])!)
}

loading.animationImages = images
loading.animationDuration = 0.3
loading.startAnimating()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Please help. I have no clue on what to do, and I need to get this done soon. Thx!

Geode1010

Comment: Move your loop inside the viewDidLoad method. The same applies to your Image view settings

Comment: Thanks SOOOO!!!! much. I was worried about it. Thx!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a note, you can simply your loop using the Swift syntax `for name in imagesNames { images.append(UIImage(named: name)) }`